# In Active Directory, how do you select specific Organizational Units?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

For example the below will give me a certain things such as **Security Groups**, and **Distribute Groups** etc.

- OU=Domain Controllers,DC=abc,DC=local OU=**Distribution**
- Groups,OU=MyBusiness,DC=abc,DC=local OU=**Security**
- Groups,OU=MyBusiness,DC=abc,DC=local
- OU=SBSComputers,OU=Computers,OU=MyBusiness,DC=abc,DC=local
- OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups,DC=abc,DC=local

But I want specifically just users that are enabled and have a Job title.

I've tried looking for this type of information, but have some up with mostly other formats which I don't know how to translate to the above examples. I.e. this works as

```
(&(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(title=*)(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person))(!(userAccountControl=514)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Microsoft Active Directory, you do not. At least not in a single LDAP Query.

There is an [ExtensibleMatch search filter](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch#section-ExtensibleMatch-SearchWithinTwoContainers) that can allow this, but at least the last time I checked, it is NOT supported by Microsoft Active Directory

You will need to perform a search to each OU and combine the results within "Code".